# Можно ли получить имя класса, с которым связано поле модели Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Можно ли как-то узнать с каким классом связано поле `some_value` объекта `some_object`?

```py
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    some_value = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None, null=True)


some_object = SomeModel.objects.get(id=1)
```

Название класса текущего объекта в `some_value` можно было бы получить как-нибудь так:

```py
some_object = SomeModel.objects.get(id=1)
some_value_class = some_object.some_value.__class__.__name__
```

Но проблема в том, что `some_value` может быть и `None`, тогда я получу `NoneType`. А как получить именно не класс текущего объекта, с которым связан мой объект, а название модели, которое используется в связи?

Comment: у NoneType нет связей и ничего от него не получить.

Comment: @eri не, я не об этом. Связанный объект может оказаться не только объектом `OtherModel`, но и `NonType`, если объект пока ни с чем не связан. Но заранее я этого не знаю.

Comment: В момент, когда Вы сделали "=" - там вышла ссылка на NoneType. С этим ничего не поделать, @eri прав.

Comment: попробуйте dir(some_object) когда он на None, сами всё увидите.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Либо я чего-то не понимаю, либо я неправильно объясняю. Попробую еще раз. Допустим я создал объект класса `SomeModel`. Я точно знаю, что у него есть поле some_value. Но я не знаю с какой моделью оно связано. В моем примере оно связано с `OtherModel`. Вот именно название этого класса (OtherModel) я и хочу получить. Как мне это сделать?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич грубо говоря, я хочу узнать объект какого класса я могу записать в поле some_value.

Comment: SomeModel._meta.get_field('some_value').rel.to.__class__.__name__ попробуйте :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
some_value_class = some_object._meta.get_field('some_value').target_field.model
```

Comment: Почти получилось) Получилось название в нижнем регистре. То есть прочитать можно, а использовать потом этот класс не получится)

Comment: Вот так будет то, что я спрашивал `some_value_class = some_object._meta.get_field('some_value').target_field.model`.  Исправьте, пожалуйста

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров исправил